# Rigid motion which is not a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

From *Linear Algebra Done Wrong*:

> Give an example of a rigid motion in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, $T(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$, which is not a linear transformation.

where a rigid motion was defined as a transformation $f : V \to V$ on an inner product space $V$ such that

\begin{align}
\left\Vert f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{y}) \right\Vert = \left\Vert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \right\Vert && \text{$\forall\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in V$}.
\end{align}

I've so far found examples of transformations which are linear and not rigid (such as $T(z) = \alpha \cdot z$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, $z = x + iy$) and transformations that are neither linear nor rigid (such as $T(x + iy) = 2x - y + iy$). Translations ($T(z) = z + a$, $a \in \mathbb{C}$) appear to be ruled out by the condition that $T(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$. Beyond this, I'm not sure how to proceed. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Look for a map that is linear with respect to coefficients from $\Bbb R$, but not linear with respect to coefficients from $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the conjugation map $T: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $z \mapsto \overline{z}$. This is a rigid motion, intuitively because conjugation corresponds to reflection through the real axis and formally since if we let $z = x_1 + iy_1$ and $w = x_2 + iy_2$, we have

\begin{align}\lVert \overline{z} - \overline{w} \rVert &= \lVert (x_1 - iy_1) - (x_2 - iy_2) \rVert \\
&= \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_2 - y_1)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2} \\
&=\lVert z-w \rVert 
\end{align}

However, it is not linear since $T(\alpha z) = \overline{\alpha z} = \overline{\alpha} T(z)$. $T$ is in fact antilinear.